# MVC 4 WebApi 404 when published to production

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7.5

I've been working on a new MVC 4 application and in the development environment everything has been working correctly, yet after deploying to our production environment I've found that my WebApi's no longer resolve and as a result I'm only getting 404's when I try to use my api's

I've checked my web.config and I can't find anything that's as miss and I've made sure that I've got the following in my web.config

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"></modules>
```

however this is not helping either.

I've also in an attempt to make sure that the server would run the MVC 4 project I've even installed the MVC4 framework which has not helped either.

Comment: Have you tried just accessing the URI that the API _should_ be calling? I ran into a problem once where it was calling the wrong URL in production, but was fine on localhost because it was somehow relative to the page it was calling from. I forget the actual fix, although it involved making the path it called relative to the server instead of the page.

Comment: I have no idea what just happened, but now they're starting to act the way they're supposed to how ever all I did was clear the application from the temporary internet files in the Microsoft.NET folder